# How can I nicely overlay fits for multiple arrays with ListPlot or ListLogPlot?

Tags: fitting, plotting

I'm plotting multiple lists with ListPlot[] or ListLogPlot[]:

```
ListLogPlot[{ListA, ListB, ListC, ListD, ListE}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, Automatic}]
```

I also have fits, $(f_a,f_b,f_c,f_d,f_e)$ for the data in each of the lists.  How can I overlay the fits in the same color and for the same $(x,y)$ range?

Comment: Could you post a minimal example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some data:

```
data = Map[Sin[# Range@100] + # &, {1, 5, 3, 6}] // N;
```

Create some fits:

```
fits = LinearModelFit[#, g, g] & /@ data;
```

Plot the data:

```
g1 = ListLogPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, Automatic}, Joined -> True];
```

Plot the fits:

```
g2 = ListLinePlot[Log@Thread[#[Range[0, 100]]]& /@ fits, PlotRange->{{0, 100},Automatic}]
```

Combine the plots:

```
Show[g1,g2]
```

> [image]